# Reduce DRY code for almost identical multiple variables in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform 0.12.6 and trying to create an object like:

```
variable "dc1" {
  type = object({
    A = object({ a = number })
    B = object({ a = number })
    C = object({ a = number })
    ...(12 times)...
```

Now, This is a reduced version of code, the original one is now 200+ lines.

I can't use `list(object({...}))` because I want to make sure that the user knows that they are entering the value of `a` for `A` or `B` or so on.

Is there a way to avoid writing `object({ a = number })`  again and again?

---

**Edit:**

As, asked in the comments below, add a more general information about what I am trying to do:

I want to have 12 almost identical `kubernetes_deployment` resources, only some settings change in these 12 instances, like `image`, `name` etc.
Now, these 12 deployments are a part of a module, so the user will simply `source` this module and set the value of like

```
dc1 = {
    A = { a = number }
    B = { a = number }
    C = { a = number }
}
```

I don't mind changing my approach to the as long as user knows they know that they are setting the value of `a` for `A`.

I could simply use:

```
    A = object({ a = number })
    B = object({ a = number })
    C = object({ a = number })
```

to avoid making it look complicated but that is also a lot of DRY code because `object({ a = number })` is repeated for all instances.

Comment: This sounds very much like an X Y problem. Can you state your problem in a broader way? Right now it sounds like you've got a horrendously complicated object for the caller of your module to configure. Do you really need that? If you have a ton of things (such as a whole data centre) then that leads to a very large blast radius as well if your Terraform config or state gets mucked up.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thanks for the suggestion, added more general information, I would be happy to add more information should it be required.